# gRPC (grpc-js): Received RST_STREAM with code 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, grpc, google-cloud-run

I have a problem with gRPC: sometimes I get RST_STREAM with code 0 instead of an INTERNAL error.

@grpc/grpc-js: 1.8.11 (both client and server)
NodeJS: 16.18.0
GCP: Cloud Run

I have that problem only when the server running in Cloud. Also tested locally and works fine, without RST_STREAM error.
In logs on the server, I see INTERNAL errors (as expected), but on the client sometimes RST_STREAM with code 0.

I noticed that when I get "Received RST_STREAM with code 0" there are no "Received server trailers" [in the logs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2004#issuecomment-1452059623).

Also, I asked for help on GitHub and the contributor [thinks](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2004#issuecomment-1457238838) that it can be a provider proxy, which makes sense.

Logs and code examples can be found [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2004#issuecomment-1452059623).

EDIT.
**Solved:** https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2004#issuecomment-1694188848

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: How to fix "Received RST_STREAM with code 0"? I always want to see (on the client) the same error that the server throws.

Comment: You acknowledge in the question that the problem is likely in a proxy that you don't control. You say that you filed a support ticket, and there likely isn't anything more you can do about it.

Comment: I said that I'd open a support ticket. Then I checked my plan and understood that I couldn't do so and I decided to ask here on StackOverflow. Maybe someone already solves it or has relevant experience that can help me.

Comment: SOLVED: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2004#issuecomment-1694188848